# Detecting items in the same position of different lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.7

I have a csv file with multiple lines and multiple entries in each line. I know how to convert each line of the csv into lists.

e.g   FROM                          TO

```
  1,x,2                       [1,x,2]
  3,x,4                       [3,x,4]
  5,y,6                       [5,y,6]
  7,y,8                       [7,y,8]
```

But I don't know how I can do through each list can't find the items what are at the same position, but in different lists. I want to be able to detect the 'x' and 'y' (and any other items at the same position in the subsequent lists).

Also, once I can detect and differentiate between the x, the y, etc..., I then want to collate and analyze another item of matching lists.

e.g

[1,x,2]
[3,x,4]

collate the 2 and 4, as their lists have x.

[5,y,6]
[7,y,8]

collate the 6 and 8, as their lists have y.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to build a collection of all the items that share a certain property is to put them in a dictionary that's keyed on that property.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import List, Dict, Tuple, Union

Entry = Union[int, str]
csv: List[List[Entry]] = [
    [1,'x',2],
    [3,'x',4],
    [5,'y',6],
    [7,'y',8]
]

index: Dict[Tuple[int, Entry], List[List[Entry]]] = defaultdict(list)

for row in csv:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        # Key on a tuple of i and the entry, e.g. (1, 'x') 
        index[(i, row[i])].append(row)

for key in index:
    if len(index[key]) > 1:
        print("index %d contains entry %s in multiple lists:" % key)
        print(index[key])
```

produces the following output:

```
index 1 contains entry x in multiple lists:
[[1, 'x', 2], [3, 'x', 4]]
index 1 contains entry y in multiple lists:
[[5, 'y', 6], [7, 'y', 8]]
```

Comment: Thank you so for your solution. I'm having a little trouble adapting it. My 'x','y', etc are words, not numbers. And I believe your solution requires them to be integers. Do you have any advice on how I can adapt this for text/string?

Comment: My solution specifically allows for them being strings -- `'x'` and `'y'` are both string literals, and I defined `Entry` as being either `int` or `str` (that's what the `Union` type is indicating).

Comment: There's also nothing in the code that requires `Entry` to have a specific type; you could substitute it for `Any` and everything else would work exactly the same.